# What UserAgent is used by Hosted Web Apps created by Windows App Studio?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have created a Hosted Web App using Windows [App Studio](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us). But in order to track it's usage in Google Analytics, I need to know what UserAgent agent a Hosted Web App uses. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Hosted Web Apps actually use a WebView control (with some restictions) in order to show the web content within the app. You can track request becoming from your Hosted Web App when the user agent contains "MSAppHost" in it:

*"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; **MSAppHost/3.0**) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"*

Here you have more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx